# Are questions about war books, detective stories, or thrillers accepted here?

Tags: discussion, scope

If I post questions that are excerpts from war books and which are not intelligible to me, will these questions be accepted and answered? Are questions asked from detective stories and thrillers well received?

Comment: There is never guarantee of any question being answered, regardless of genre. That depends entirely on whether anyone feels able to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange! Please consider taking our [tour](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tour) and checking out the [help centre](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about how this site works - specifically, the page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) may be useful to you.

Our site scope isn't limited by genre. Questions about war novels, detective stories, thrillers, or any other genre of fiction (and even some non-fiction) are all fine here.

Posting an excerpt from a book and asking about its meaning is also an acceptable type of question - you can find many of these under the [meaning](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) tag. Please be clear about which part you don't understand. Sometimes these questions are just a matter of explaining the meaning of words or phrases in English, but sometimes there is some deeper contextual analysis to be done in order to understand their significance within the work of literature.