# Why were my questions about two books by Cornelius Ryan on war not answered?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I posted questions about two books that are written by Cornelius Ryan, but they were not answered or commented upon. The questions appear as "recently deleted questions", because now they have been deleted. Are the questions not worthy enough to expect an answer? The books are *The Longest Day* and *A Bridge Too Far*. I would like to know why my questions were deleted and not answered. In response to [a question of mine](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1383/17), you answered that questions about books of war are answered on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You posted your questions on the *meta* site: [The War book “THE LONGEST DAY” written by CORNELIUS RYAN](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1469/17) and [A non-fiction book by Cornelius Ryan-“A bridge too far”](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1470/17). As you have been informed many times in comments, this meta site (literature.meta.stackexchange.com) is for questions **about Literature Stack Exchange**: e.g. for asking which types of questions are on-topic here, which tags should be used, how site policies should be defined, etc.

If you have questions **about books or works of literature**, they should be posted on the main site (literature.stackexchange.com). So far you have posted nothing there about any books by Cornelius Ryan.

If you continue posting questions on the wrong site, they will continue to be closed and deleted.

Comment: I know that the purposes of the two sites are completely different.BUT when the main site won't take my question but the meta site would, what is to be done? I have "comment everywhere privilege".The books were subjects of discussion for many years in our house. I*emphasized text* am ready to delete the questions if you permit me.

Comment: @user37920 "what is to be done?" Please see the [help centre page on question bans](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) to answer that question. If you continue posting off-topic questions on meta, they will continue being deleted and eventually you will be question-blocked on meta too. No need for you to delete those questions, as they are already deleted.